# Wix Heat include files from a folder that are listed in another xml or txt and exclude the rest

Tags: xml, xslt, wix, heat

I would like to harvest a directory using Heat which contains a lot of files and not all of them should go into installation. However, i have a list of files that should be included in another XML in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileSystemList>
   <File Path="\some_folder\some.file" />
   ...
</FileSystemList>
```

It could just as well be a simple text file with one file per line.

I already have a XSL transform which i can specify a file to exclude but it's not really appropriate if you have hundreds of files. 
I know almost nothing about XSL (been using samples i could find) so i would appreciate a help to somehow include this xml/txt file into the XSL which heat will use and exclude the files in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heat doesn't support that. Instead, use your build engine (e.g., MSBuild) to create a staging area that contains only the files you want to harvest.

Comment: Yeah i found out that Heat doesn't support that but i though maybe i could do that in a transform file (XSL). For example i can use 

`<xsl:key name="exclude-files" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'Config.xml')]" use="@Id"/>
 <xsl:template match="*[key('exclude-files', @Id)]" />` to exclude certain file and i would like to do the opposite to include only ones listed, in my case a list in another file and if XSL support something like `include`

Comment: I got tired trying to learn XSL so i just went and did exactly what you said, use MSBuild for staging and then harvesting, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, XSLT removes all xml files except "Config.xml":

```
<xsl:key name="XmlToRemove" 
match="wix:Component[ substring( wix:File/@Source, string-length( wix:File/@Source ) - 3) = '.xml' and not (contains(wix:File/@Source, Config.xml))]" 
use="@Id"/>
...     
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('XmlToRemove', @Id)]" />
```